# Convert Python Script to .exe that will work on all/most versions of Windows

Tags: python, windows, py2exe, pyinstaller

I am aware how to convert a Python script to an Windows Executable file(.exe) using Py2Exe, PyInstaller and etc.

**But is there a way to convert a Python script to an .exe that will work on all the following versions of Windows: Windows XP to Windows 8?**

Keep in mind my Python script is very simple and does NOT use any libraries like pyGTK or wxPython. Its just a simple console script that lists all files in a directory and writes it to a file.

So if I were to compile the following script using Py2Exe on my Windows 7 64bit computer, would that .exe work on ALL the following versions of Windows: Windows XP to Windows 8? I am hoping I wont need to create a 32bit version then a 64bit version.

```
import os

def main():
  #TODO: get command line arguments
  files = listdir("\")
  out   = open('outfile.txt', 'w')
  out.write(files)
  out.close()

main()
```

Comment: If your just looking for the functionality, and it doesn't have to be a script, you can just run (for example) `dir C:\ /B > outfile.txt` in the command prompt

Comment: Notice the weird syntax hightlighting on your code? You'll need to write `files = listdir("\\")` whether you compile it or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I roll up my wxPython-based app using PyInstaller on Windows Vista/32. After building the executable, I roll that into an installer using InnoSetup. I have customers running everything from XP to 8 in both 32 and 64-bit modes from the same setup executable made in this fashion.

I'm considering building 64-bit versions but so far nobody's asked for it and it hasn't seemed necessary.

I've tried py2exe, cxFreeze, and PyInstaller on Windows, and so far PyInstaller is my favorite. I ran into issues with py2exe on some platforms; cxFreeze at the time couldn't handle putting in version resources (it can now) and PyInstaller seemed to "just work" the quickest right out of the box.

So to cut to the chase, no you don't need to build both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of your app, if you don't care that on 64-bit Windows it'll run in 32-bit mode through the WOW virtual machine.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I ran into the same problem with my own wxPython app and using Py2Exe. I compiled on 64bit windows 7 and people had issues running the .exe on Windows Vista. So thats why I am asking. So you think if I compile on Windows Vista 32bit that the .exe will work ok on something like Windows XP? For me it has to work on XP as many customers use this.

Comment: Yes, most of my customers are still on XP, and the exe I build with PyInstaller on Vista works just fine for them.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to create on the lowest system you want to support.  IT should then be forward compatible.  32bit will run on 64bit Windows just fine.

Comment: are you saying I need to run Py2Exe and the script on a Windows XP computer and the resulting .exe should support all more current versions of Windows?

Comment: @JakeM yes it should be like that.

Comment: why? that is the problem with doing in in any windows other than older ones ?

Comment: because it might bundle version of python which no longer supports older OS I guess.