# How to compile python code to exe for different versions of Windows

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I'm using windows 10 and by using pyinstaller I compile my python script to exe file.I want to distribute that file over different versions of Windows.But if the target OS is not updated to match my OS configurations, that exe file raises errors on runtime.

For example the program I compiled in my OS gave an error as "api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll is missing" during runtime when run into Windows 8.1.The problem is not in bit version.It's in appropriate versions of API.

So my question is, how can I compile my python source code to exe so that it can run on different/lesser versions of Windows ?

Comment: You are probably looking for embedding Cython, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2743448/4974175).

Comment: Thanks for answering everyone. I actually found a similar answer in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289979/convert-python-script-to-exe-that-will-work-on-all-most-versions-of-windows?rq=1)